# how to connect sony xperia sgpt121 tablet with eclipse on windows 7 x64?

Tags: android, eclipse, tablet, android-virtual-device, drivers

i own a sony xperia tablet model sgpt121fr .

i use eclipse and google sdk to develop android application, i already right success connected my smartphone sony to eclipse AVD.

but my tablet is not recongnized by eclipse AVD.
When i connected my tablet to my computer, it is not reconnignzed and drivers seems missed. They called "sgpt12" something..
i tried to find it on sony website but no success.
i found this two address :
http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/support-info.pl?info_id=878
and
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

but it concerns the previous version of the tablet (sony tablet S) and the next release (sony z xperia tablet). So where is the tablet xperia of 2012 drivers ?

As i said, i already succes to connect my sony smartphone xperia, so i'm aware of the procedure (usb optin..etc), i just missing the drivers for the tablet xperia !

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

try search for driver of table xperia here:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

i think it is:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-tablet-z-sgp311-sgp312-driver/

Comment: no, you're wrong. you provided a link for the xperia Z tablet (2013), and i search for the xperia tablet (wothout the Z from 2012)

Comment: and this dont help? http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/read-me-how-to-get-drivers-for-all-sony-smartphones/

Comment: i already install pc compagnon and it is useful to connect the internal memory of the tablet (to transfert picture, or make update..etc). it doesn't provide the way to be discover and connected into android virtual device in eclipse.

Comment: i aslo did this http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/#installsdk 

but it didn't help to provide the usb debbuging throught avd

Answer (score 0):

i finaly find the solution.

you have to edit yourself the android_winusb.inf file located in your sdk folder. Mine is at c:\android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\

Then, in both section [Google.NTx86]  AND [Google.NTamd64] you have to add this same line :

;SONY Xperia Tablet S
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_054C&PID_06AD&MI_01

end reload (or updad you inf drivers) into windows and retest the connection.

it workd for me !
and it works for japan people :

http://signalshonan.ddo.jp/modules/d3diary/index.php?page=detail&bid=99

and it works for canadian people :

http://zfmich.blogspot.fr/2013/03/how-to-connect-sony-xperia-s-tablet.html?showComment=1367590189844#c49206077027504622

thanks me !